# Can the Bevel modifier make the same angled edges when the box is not exactly a cube?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

It seems that the angle is sort of proportional to the lengths of the two faces. For example, the box in the screenshot below has a shorter height when compared to the width or the height, so the edge between the top face and a side face is less rounded than the edge between two side faces.

But I want the same shaped edges for all edges. I have tried changing some of the parameters, but I could not make them the same. Is it possible to get what I want with the Bevel modifier, or do I have to not use the modifier and manually round edges separately using the Bevel tool of the Edit mode?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when your object scale is non-uniform. *Object > Apply > Scale* should solve it.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Thanks. It did make the edges look the same. I am still not understanding why there is a separate "scale" in addition to "dimensions" so that I have to manually make the scale to 1 after resizing an object, but maybe I have to ask another question for that.

Comment: Happy to help :). Feel free to ask a new question regarding the scale panel, you might get some interesting answers.